# How can I fix the 'address already in use' error when running 'docker-compose up -d' with nginxproxymanager?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm hosting a website already in Ubuntu and I just installed Docker but when I run the docker-compose up -d command i'm getting this error

ERROR: for ac8ca90f10bc_nginxproxymanager  Cannot start service app: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nginxproxymanager (351524a664634bc19b7f697db0a35b7d3933abf1327b62823b3a051f648399d5): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nginxproxymanager (351524a664634bc19b7f697db0a35b7d3933abf1327b62823b3a051f648399d5): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

What can I do on the nginx config file to have this corrected and my website working on docker?

I am hosting my website on port 80 & 443 and I want to have nginxproxymanager working, I already try to open mydomain.com:81 but nginxproxymanager wont opent